# When do we need to add reference to the stage from one class to another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, reference, stage

When do we need to pass reference to the stage from one as3 class to another like in this tutorial

http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-flash-games-for-beginners-firing-weapons-with-delays

he added a ref to the stage from the bullet class to the ship class

as I understand a reference is needed when we want to use a function in a certain class from another class but why do we have to reference the stage isn't it only one stage for the whole project or each class has it's own stage ?

I am very confused

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only objects that are connected to a stage will be shown on screen. In the tutorial he is adding the lasers onto the stage display list so that it appears on screen. Until it is added, it will not be rendered regardless of the `visible` property.

See [this](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/) for more info about the display list.

Comment: Plus, if its not fully added, the `stage` and its properties can't be accessed. This is why Flashdevelop creates an `init` method for its projects.

Answer (score 0):

@Geotarget is correct, but the answer is a little bit indirect.

Objects that are not on the display list do not actually have a reference to `stage`.  So if, for example, you create a `var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();` which is not added to the display list (as in `addChild(mc)`), then `mc.stage` will be `null`.  (Also, checking `if(mc.stage){[...]}` is also a way to verify if the `MovieClip` is part of the display list yet.)

So you can pass a reference to the `stage` to non-display-list objects to allow them access to things like `stageWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a reference is needed when you wanna have to access a function present in that particular class ( to which reference belongs). This is one of the uses.

There is only one stage for the whole project.

In the tutorial you are following, both the classes are using the reference of a COMMON Stage, so that both of them can access the Stage. 
It's like giving the address of a place to two people. So that both of them can go there. Naturally, giving addresses doesnot mean, we are building two places for each of them.

V.